# How to store/format these infinite data filter conditions

Tags: php, logic

I'm developing an app that will look up an email inbox and save specific emails as part of it's functionality. What happens is an imap connection is made and then all emails that are set as UNSEEN are retrieved. Each email is checked against pre-defined conditions and then saved to a DB if they are met. These conditions can be set by the user and can be the following:

Subject

- Contains string
- Does not contain string

Body

- Contains string
- Does not contain string

From

- Specific address

Conditions can be "chained" for instance:

```
FILTER WHERE  
Subject CONTAINS "Order Confirmation"
AND
Email FROM "billyjones26@gmail.com" OR "billyjones26@googlemail.com"
```

I'm having trouble thinking of how to format and store these conditions. I need to have a GUI where the user can create these conditions.

My questions is how should I store these conditions? I.e some sort of DB table structure, or maybe converted into a string format and stored in a single table. There needs to be a unlimited number of conditions for an unlimited number of users, and I need to know what operators there are, etc.

Hope that's enough information!

*** EDIT FOR MICHAEL ***

So I can create the conditions and save them. Now I'm retrieving them and trying to match emails. I created a filter with one condition: Subject contains 'TEST'. Only one email should match this but somehow all emails are being added to the matched array.

**My controller that is getting the emails/conditions:**

```
public function check_email(){
    $filters = $this->filters_model->get_filters($owner_id=1);
    foreach($filters->result() as $filter){
        $emails = $this->gmail->get_emails($mailbox_id = $filter->mailbox_id, $limit = 10);

        $matched = array();
        $conditions = unserialize($filter->conditions);

        foreach($emails as $email){
            if($conditions->isMet($email) == TRUE){
                $matched[] = $email;
            }
        }

        echo count($matched);
        echo '<pre>'.$filter->title.'<br /.';
        print_r($conditions);
        echo '</pre><br />-----';
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Keyvalueprerequisite.php**

This seems to work fine as a var_dump of `stripos($subject, $this->value) !== FALSE;` shows only TRUE for 1 email.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Keyvalueprerequisite {

    private $key;
    private $comparator;
    private $value;

    public function __construct($key, $comparator, $value){
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->comparator = $comparator;
        $this->value = $value;
    }


    public function isMet(&$context)
    {
        switch ($this->key) {

            case "subject":

                $subject = $context["subject"];
                if ($this->comparator === "in"){
                    return stripos($subject, $this->value) !== FALSE;
                } else if ($this->comparator === "!in") {
                    return stripos($subject, $this->value) === FALSE;
                }

                return FALSE;

                break;

            case "body":

                $body = $context["body"];

                if ($this->comparator === "in") {
                    return stripos($body, $this->value) !== FALSE;
                } else if ($this->comparator === "!in") {
                    return stripos($body, $this->value) === FALSE;
                }

                return FALSE;

                break;

            case "from_address":

                $from = $context["from"];

                if ($this->comparator === "=") {
                    return $this->value === $from;
                } else if ($this->comparator === "!=") {
                    return $this->value !== $from;
                } else{
                    return false;
                }

                break;

            default:
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

**Prerequisistegroup.php**

Something might not be quite write here. a var_dump of `$result = $result && $is_met` returns true for each of the 10 emails.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Prerequisitegroup {

    private $type;
    private $prerequisites;

    public function __construct($type = 'AND'){
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function add(){
        foreach(func_get_args() as $prerequisite){
          $this->prerequisites[] = $prerequisite;
        }
    }

    public function isMet(&$context)
    {
        if (empty($this->prerequisites) === FALSE) {
            $result = TRUE;

            foreach ($this->prerequisites as $prerequisite) {
                $is_met = $prerequisite->isMet($context);
                if ($this->type === 'AND') {
                    $result = $result && $is_met;
                    if ($result === FALSE) {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                } else {
                    $result = $result || $is_met;
                    if ($result === TRUE) {
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }


}
```

**These are my conditions that are being checked:**

```
string(3) "AND"
  ["prerequisites":"Prerequisitegroup":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(Prerequisitegroup)#23 (2) {
      ["type":"Prerequisitegroup":private]=>
      string(2) "OR"
      ["prerequisites":"Prerequisitegroup":private]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(Keyvalueprerequisite)#24 (3) {
          ["key":"Keyvalueprerequisite":private]=>
          string(7) "subject"
          ["comparator":"Keyvalueprerequisite":private]=>
          string(2) "in"
          ["value":"Keyvalueprerequisite":private]=>
          string(4) "TEST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you have multiple 'contains' like with 'email'? Can you have negation on 'contains'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a CMS I solved a similar problem, by abstracting the conditions (Prerequisites) into two classes: Prerequisite and PrerequisiteGroup (a subclass of the former, and then serialized them, or more precisely *the object*, since there would only be one into a BLOB in MySQL.

The advantage of this was that I could simply deserialize the object and invoke an `isMet()` function without bothering about the depth or complexity of the perquisites. The disadvantage was of course that I couldn't make DB queries on this objects. But that wasn't a problem in this particular case, and from your own suggestions I think it isn't in yours as well.

The `Prerequisite` class (or interface) implements one method `isMet($context)` that tells you where your condition is true or not. The context in your case would be the $email to be examined. E.g. if from email matches "billyjones26@gmail.com".

The `PrerequisiteGroup` represents `AND` and `OR`, in a simplified way. The default way to group conditions is by

Here is an example of creating and storing the conditions:

```
$c1 = new KeyValuePrerequisite("EmailFrom", "=", "billyjones26@gmail.com");
$c2 = new KeyValuePrerequisite("EmailFrom", "=", "billyjones26@googlemail.com");
$c3 = new KeyValuePrerequisite("Subject", "in", "Order Confirmation");

$from_condition = new PrerequisiteGroup('or');
$from_condition->add($c1, $c2);

$final_condition = new PrerequisiteGroup($c3, $from_condition); // defaults to and

$db->query("INSERT INTO conditions SET user_id = %i, conditions = %l", $user_id, serialize($final_condition));
```

Here is an example usage:

```
// Fetch conditions

$email_conditions = $user->getEmailConditions()

// Connect to your inbox and fetch relevant emails

$matching_emails = array();
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    if ($email_conditions->isMet($email) {
        $matching_emails[] = $email;
    }
}
```

Prerequisite interface:

```
interface Prerequisite 
{
    /**
     * Must return TRUE or FALSE.
     */
    public function isMet(&$context);
}
```

KeyValuePrerequisite implementation (in my implementation this actually an abstract class but for your purpose you can implement everything here, you could call it EmailPrerequisite or EmailCondition):

```
class KeyValuePrerequisite extends PrerequisiteGroup
{
    protected $key;
    protected $comparator;
    protected $value;

    public function __construct($key, $comparator, $value = NULL)
    {
        $this->key        = $key;
        $this->comparator = $comparator;
        $this->value      = $value;
    }

    public function isMet(&$context)
    {
        switch ($this->key) {

            case "Subject":

                $subject = $context["subject"];

                if ($this->comparator === "in") }
                    return stripos($subject, $this->value) !== FALSE;
                } else if ($this->comparator === "not int") {
                    return stripos($subject, $this->value) === FALSE;
                }

                return FALSE;

                break;

            case "EmailFrom":

                $from = $context["from"];

                return $this->value === $from;

                break;

            default:
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

PrerequisiteGroup implementation:

```
class PrerequisiteGroup implements Prerequisite
{
    private $type;
    private $prerequisites;

    public function __construct($type = 'AND')
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function add(Prerequisite $prerequisite)
    {
        if ($prerequisite instanceof Prerequisite) {
            $this->prerequisites[] = $prerequisite;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unknown Prerequisite type ' . get_class($prerequisite));
        }
    }

    public function isMet(&$context)
    {
        if (empty($this->prerequisites) === FALSE) {
            $result = $this->type === 'AND';
            foreach ($this->prerequisites as $prerequisite) {
                $is_met = $prerequisite->isMet($context);
                if ($this->type === 'AND') {
                    $result = $result && $is_met;
                    if ($result === FALSE) {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                } else {
                    $result = $result || $is_met;
                    if ($result === TRUE) {
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

**GUI**

When it comes to GUI there are several approaches/patterns. The most common, I think, for email related apps is to have a number of rows of expressions that are ANDed and a [+] to add more conditions:

```
Row 1: [select: subject] [select:contains] [input:"Order Confirmation"]
```

When it comes to the `from` we need to express OR. This is hard to do with just rows. This is where the concept of a Prerequisite or Condition group becomes handy. You simply add a new row which is a group and let the user to choose to use AND or OR.

The *outer* group is an AND group.

So the GUI elements are fairly easy to transform into code and vice versa - especially with the KeyValuePrerequisite impl. of Prerequisite.

Hope this helps or at least sparked some ideas to solve your problem.

Comment: Note that I had several source and use-cases for this concept. Like conditions for content being shown, prerequisites for discounts being given or campaigns activated and shown (in a eCommerce solution). Since you only have to operate on e-mails, could probably simply it a lot.

Comment: Wow thanks that's certainly given me some ideas to work on. You're coding and problem solving is a bit above my level but I'll try use what you've given to come to a solution. Will probably be back with a question or two first!

Comment: Hi again Michael, so far I can capture the conditions from the user, create the object, serialize it and store it in the db. I'm attempting to implement isMet() but I'm not really sure how to do it. I have edited my answer to add the unserialized object I get when I'm about to check. Would you be able to explain the operation of the isMet() function please and how it handles the unknown AND / OR 's. Thanks again!

Comment: I've updated the examples to be more complete. I hope this helps, otherwise just ask again.

Comment: The Prerequisite and Prerequisite are now the complete implementations. The KeyValuePrerequisite is a little simple but should do the trick. Nothing is tested.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm at the point of checking matching emails but even though one of the emails should match I'm getting a match on all 10 emails I try. I've added code to my question. Would you have a look and see if you can spot any bugs? Thanks

Comment: I just tried to run your code and it works perfectly. This is my stub: `<?php

require 'Keyvalueprerequisite.php';
require 'Prerequisitegroup.php';

$conditions = new Keyvalueprerequisite("subject", "in", "test");

$emails = array(
 array("subject" => "Testing 123"),
 array("subject" => "This is just spam"),
 array("subject" => "Testosterone"),
 array("subject" => "Autodaily")
);

$matched = array();

foreach($emails as $email){
    if($conditions->isMet($email) == TRUE){
        $matched[] = $email;
    }
}

foreach ($matched as $email) {
 echo "Subject: " . $email['subject'] . "\n";
}
`

Comment: As you can see it filters out exactly the two emails that contains TEST. I'll try to make a more complex example using your code.

Comment: Just tried this composite condition - works fine as well:
`$c1 = new Keyvalueprerequisite("subject", "in", "test");
$c2 = new Keyvalueprerequisite("from_address", "=", "mblarsen@gmail.com");
$conditions = new Prerequisitegroup();
$conditions->add($c1, $c2);
`

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is when I'm creating the conditions, I seem to have a lost 'type' property. AND seems to work but I tried with an OR group: `$condition = new Keyvalueprerequisite("subject", "in", "Test"); $condition1 = new Keyvalueprerequisite("subject", "in", "spam"); $final= new Prerequisitegroup('OR'); $final->add($condition, $condition1);` which should match 2 of the emails but matches all

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16032/discussion-between-michael-and-iamjonesy)